# Extracting small word parts (quadgrams) from text using R

Tags: strings, r

I would like to extracts small word parts (quadgrams) from text. Example:

```
hello world
```

results in:

```
_hel, hell, ello, llo_, lo_w ...
```

This my basic attempt thus far:

```
text <- "hello world"

number_of_characters <- nchar(text)
quad_gram_list <- ""[-1]

for (i in 1:number_of_characters) {

    end <- i + 3
    if (end > number_of_characters) {
        end <- number_of_characters
    }

    temp <- substring(text, i, end)

    if (nchar(temp) == 4) {
        quad_gram_list <- append(quad_gram_list, temp)
    }
}
```

Any improvement suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your loop approach works but seems a bit convoluted. For instance you could rewrite the `for` loop this way:

```
for (i in 1:number_of_characters) {

  end <- i + 3

  if (end <= number_of_characters) {
    temp <- substring(text, i, end)
    quad_gram_list <- append(quad_gram_list, temp)
  }
}
```

But anyway it's generally better to avoid loops in R.

Also note that:

- you should use `character(0)` instead of `""[-1]`
- `:` is to be avoided because of undesired behaviour on edge cases. It's better to use `seq_len()`.

Here are two alternative solutions:

**1) Using base R:**

```
unlist(lapply(seq_len(nchar(text) - 3), function(i) substring(text, i, i + 3)))
# [1] "hell" "ello" "llo " "lo w" "o wo" " wor" "worl" "orld"
```

**2) Using `tokenizers`:**

```
library(tokenizers)

tokenize_character_shingles(
  text,
  n = 4,
  strip_non_alphanum = FALSE,
  simplify = TRUE
)
# [1] "hell" "ello" "llo " "lo w" "o wo" " wor" "worl" "orld"
```

Comment: `substring` is vectorized so you can do: `start <- head(seq(nchar(text)), -3); stop  <- tail(seq(nchar(text)), -3); substring(text, start, stop)`